# After attempting to set up code . on my wsl environment, commands have stopped working

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh

I inserted `export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"` in `~/.zshrc` and after saving and quitting, my commands stopped working. I can't access the rc file to modify it in any way as far as I know. nvim/vi do not work either.

Comment: If you've broken your PATH, you can still use programs by their full path ex. `/usr/bin/vi ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

- First, for recovery, exit Ubuntu and `wsl ~ -e zsh -f`.  This should start Zsh without processing your `~/.zshrc`.  Alternatively, `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc` if the first version doesn't work.

  You can then correct any mistakes in your startup files.
- More importantly, it looks like you are trying to use the Linux version of Visual Studio Code under WSL.  While this should work, VSCode and WSL are designed for interoperability using the *Windows* version of VSCode.

  I would recommend:

  - Uninstalling the Linux version of VSCode (assuming that's what you've installed).
  - Install the Windows version of VSCode
  - Add the [WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) to VSCode (also included in the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)).

  The Windows version of VSCode is added to the Windows path automatically, which should be appended to the Linux/WSL path automatically assuming you haven't disabled that feature in `/etc/wsl.conf`.

  When you call `code .`, a shell script provided by VSCode will install a server in your home directory which it will use to communicate with your WSL distribution.